# Is it possible to call the synchronisation function using a VBA command for my Exact Online report?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, invantive-control, exact-online

I'm using Invantive Control for Excel to create an Exact Online report.

I'm changing some of the values of this report with VBA in Microsoft Excel, upon which the query is based.

So I'd like to be able to trigger the download function of the synchronize button with a VBA command. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In order to synchronize the workbook you need to call:

- `I_SYNC_UPLOAD` if you just want to upload data to your database or service;
- `I_SYNC_DOWNLOAD` if you just want to download data from your database or service;
- `I_SYNC_ALL` if you want to do both of the above: first `I_SYNC_UPLOAD`, if successful `I_SYNC_DOWNLOAD`.

To sum up the steps you need to perform in order to get thing working from begin to end:

- Enable the Invantive model from the *Modeler* tab;
- Set the model in edit mode using the *Edit mode* button in the same tab;
- Open the *Developer* tab and click *Insert* then select the first item *Button (Form Control)*;
- Draw a button at a place at your disposal;
- The *Assign Macro* dialog opens automatically. Click *New* there. This opens the Visual Basic for Applications editor;
- In the menu bar, choose *Tools* and then the menu item *References*. Make sure that *InvantiveControlUDFs* is checked. Click *OK*;
- Now in your `Sub`, place the code as mentioned above, such as:

  ```
  Sub Button1_Click()
      I_SYNC_DOWNLOAD
  End Sub
  ```